# How to remove exact string from a string?

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a bunch of ids and some value inside a table in  textual form as below

```
456-678-978=>6;
567-734-565=>8;
```

where `474-484-735` is some ID followed by => where 8 is quantity and ; is where a single entity ends.

Now using preg_replace and str_replace I am not able to replace a full string such as `567-734-565=>8;` and just wanted to receive the output with only `456-678-978=>6;` as the data.

How should I replace an exact set of strings to some null or It could be possible to trim the entire string?

Any help is most appreciated

Comment: What is your actual needs? Provide an example with a suitable scenario.

Comment: i want to remove the `567-734-565=>8;`  from string `456-678-978=>6;567-734-565=>8;`

Comment: Try this: [https://3v4l.org/sJHJt](https://3v4l.org/sJHJt)

Comment: If you just want to know if your specific substring is in that text you could just check if [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) for the literal substring isn't false.

Comment: @FrayneKonok your trick worked out.. i was storing the values in variable hence i got confused..but adding " " double quotes around worked like charm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your comment: `i want to remove the 567-734-565=>8; from string 456-678-978=>6;567-734-565=>8;`, all you have to do is use `str_replace`, this is a simple way, just find the string and replace it with empty string. Below is the example-

```
$str = "456-678-978=>6;567-734-565=>8;";
echo str_replace("567-734-565=>8;", "", $str);
```

[Working Example Online](https://3v4l.org/sJHJt)